# How to get the dimension between two points in Java

Tags: java, computational-geometry

Given two `Point`s, is there a more native solution to get the area between these, than this?

```
new Dimension(one.x - other.x, one.y - other.y);
```

What I think of is something like

```
Dimension a = new Dimension(one, other);
Dimension b = one.towards(other);
```

Comment: What does this have to do with `multithreading` or `hibernate`?

Comment: @Ordous Thanks for the hint. The tags had remained from a former question which I had started editing but did not submit. The website then keeps the content of the editor which I cleared out before writing my new question. Obviously I forgot to clear out the tags, too. Fixed it.

Comment: Do you want the X/Y dimensions or the area ?

Comment: Like selecting an area with the mouse, you drag from one corner to the opposite corner. What I want is x and y length of the selection. Example answer is given below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is a bit odd, but here it is:

```
static Dimension sizeBetween(Point from, Point to) {
    Rectangle box = new Rectangle(from);
    box.add(to);
    return box.getSize();
}
```